# in a Vue/OL app, show a circle at location after zooming in

Tags: openlayers, vue.js

In my Vue app there is a button that, when clicked, zooms to the current location. The zoom is animated, and once the animation is finished, a circle should be added to the current location, which is not working at the moment.

Aside from the OL documentation I consulted specifically these sources:

This one helped me to setup "vanilla" OpenLayers in Vue:
https://dev.to/camptocamp-geo/integrating-an-openlayers-map-in-vue-js-a-step-by-step-guide-2n1p

This original OL 6.5 example shows code that is used to draw a circle at the current location:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html

I have troubles to "translate" the OL example code to Vue.

This are the main code lines that (I think) should actually do the job:

```js
// MapContainer.vue => export defaults {
data() {
  return {
    positionFeature: new Feature(),
    circle: new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 12,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#FF0000'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
          width: 12
        })
      })
    })
  }
},
mounted() {
    // Assign style to positionFeature
    this.positionFeature.setStyle(this.circle)

    this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        // features: [this.positionFeature] // <== DOES NOT WORK
        features: []
      })
    })

    this.tileLayer = new TileLayer({ source: new OSM() })

    this.olMap = new Map({
      target: this.$refs['map-root'],
      layers: [ this.tileLayer, this.vectorLayer ],
      view: this.view
    })
},
methods: {
  zoomToCurrentLocation () {
    const view = this.olMap.getView()
    view.animate({
      center: fromLonLat([...]),
      zoom: 16,
      duration: 1000
    }, this.cb_viewAnimate)
  },
  cb_viewAnimate () {
    this.createPointAtCurrentLocation()
  },
  createPointAtCurrentLocation () {
    // Get coordinates from geolocation
    /* const coordinates = this.geolocation.getPosition(); */

    // For testing purposes provide coordinates "manually":
    const coordinates = [16.3807232, 48.1918976];
    const point = new Point(coordinates);
    console.log("point =", point);

    this.positionFeature.setGeometry(              //
      coordinates ? point : null                   // 
    );                                             // <== DOES NOT WORK
    const source = this.vectorLayer.getSource()    //
    source.addFeatures(this.positionFeature)       //
  }
}
```

The idea is to setup the positionFeature and its assigned style during Vue's "mounted()" live-cycle state. Just for testing purposes I assign the positionFeature to the VectorLayer => VectorSource right away in "mounted()" as well. But that does not work either (probably because no Point was passed along, but I would expect OL to fall bak to [0,0] then - am I wrong?).

The real goal, however, is to assign the point only, once the animation of the View is finished by calling the `createPointAtCurrentLocation` function in View's `animate` callback. Various "console.logs" (not shown here) tell me that the functions are indeed called and a positionFeature is assigned. However, there is nothing to see on the map.

I prepared a minimal Codesandbox example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/openlayers-circle-at-current-location-37rw0?file=/src/components/MapContainer.vue:3373-3759

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OpenLayers geolocationn will return cordinates in view projection, but for your test data you will need to transform the Lon/Lat yourself `const coordinates = fromLonLat([16.3807232, 48.1918976]);`

Comment: Thank you very much! I could fix the manual coordinates that way! Awesome! – However, when using geolocation.getPosition(), undefined is returned... Why is that?

Comment: Using async await does not get rid of the problem either...

Comment: You need `tracking: true` in the Geolocation options to enable geolocation at startup

Comment: That indeed solves the problem! Thank you so much, Mike! - Any chance to motivate you to post your comments as real answer? Then I could upvote your input!

Comment: ...and mark the question as answered, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers geolocationn will return coordinates in view projection, but for your test data you will need to transform the Lon/Lat yourself:

```
const coordinates = fromLonLat([16.3807232, 48.1918976]);
```

You also need `tracking: true` in the Geolocation options to enable geolocation at startup  (or you could enable it later using `this.geolocation.setTracking(true);`).